# Extract Maps from List in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a list of complex maps, like so (I've simplified the maps, but really they're made up more maps):

```
[
  {
     "hooha" = {
         "foo" = { "something" = "this" }
      }
  },
  {
     "woot" = {
         "bar" = { "other_things" = "that" }
      }
  },
]
```

I need to feed this into `jsonencode()`, but first have it look like this:

```
{
   "hooha" = {
       "foo" = { "something" = "this" }
    },
   "woot" = {
       "bar" = { "other_things" = "that" }
    }
}
```

So from a list of maps, to a map of the maps.

This seemed trivial, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [`merge`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/merge) with a combination of with [`...`](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments) operator.

```
locals {
  my_list = [
    {
      "hooha" = {
        "foo" = { "something" = "this" }
      },
      "www" = {
        "aa" = {"x" = "y"}
      }
    },
    {
      "woot" = {
        "bar" = { "other_things" = "that" }
      }
    },
  ]
}

output "prepare" {
  value = merge(local.my_list...)
}
```

The output will be something like this:

```
prepare = {
  "hooha" = {
    "foo" = {
      "something" = "this"
    }
  }
  "woot" = {
    "bar" = {
      "other_things" = "that"
    }
  }
  "www" = {
    "aa" = {
      "x" = "y"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is as close to a perfect answer as possible! You even linked to the docs (that I obviously need to catch up on, because I'd never even heard of the `...` symbol).